# Selenium contextClick() hangs on Edge browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\\EdgeDriver\\" + "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"))).contextClick().build().perform();
if (driver != null) {
    driver.close();
}
```

When I run the above code, a context menu is popped up, but it does not proceed further from that. If I manually click on somewhere else, it proceeds further into the program.

- I have checked with other browser/driver, it works without any
  problem.
- I am using Selenium 2.53 and MicrosoftWebDriver 14393

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

try System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\EdgeDriver\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");

instead of

System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\EdgeDriver\" + "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");

Comment: I haven't tried yet. But, what difference will the concatenation operation make?